# How can I prepend 4 white spaces to an element and then remove them with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the user presses the tab key inside a content-editable div I prepend 4 whitespaces to the text inside that p tag like so:

```
  containerWithCaret = rangy.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode
  $(containerWithCaret).prepend '    '
```

Since the div is set to white-space pre the tab shows up fine. But now when the user presses shift + tab I am not sure how to untab the white spaces? How can simulate the delete key being pressed 4 times? I tried using jquery to set the text of the div to a substring minus the first 4 character but got messy results with the caret.

Is there a good way to untab by keeping track of how many tabs each line has and to remove them how can I simulate the delete key being pressed 4 times?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$( ".inner" ).prepend( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" );`

and for removing these spaces you can use:

`myString.replace(/ +/g, '');`

I think this will work.

happyCoding :D

Comment: Since I am using whitespace pre I do not need to use &nbsp; And the replace function seems to remove all spaces before. But the user might tab in multiple times and tab out only once. I need to account for this.

Comment: replace function will not remove all the spaces. if there is more than    one space, then it will remove that spaces.

Comment: If the user presses shift-tab I want to remove the first 4 white spaces. So if there are 12 whitespaces, and the user presses shift-tab, there should only be 8 remaining. Currently your code removes all whitespaces in front of the string.

Comment: I am not getting but I think this will help - `myString.replace(/ +/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');`